# Spring - How to use super class as responseType in postForObject method?

Tags: spring, post, resttemplate

I am trying to send post request through RestTemplate in Spring(5.1.5) and want to use super class as responseType.

These are my classes :

```
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable {
    public ParentEntity() {
    }
}

public class UserInfo extends ParentEntity {
    //fields
    public UserInfo() {
    }
    //getter&setter for fields
}
```

Now, when I tried

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(url,request,ParentEntity.class).getBody()
```

I did not get anything (Class has no fields), but with

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(url,request,Object.class).getBody()
```

I got the response and its fields.

Why I don't get response when I use super class of UserInfo (ParentEntity), but when I use Object, everything works fine?!

Comment: and what you're using to serialize/de-serialize? jackson?

Comment: @VibrantVivek I did not use anything for serialize/de-serialize. I thank postForEntity method must handle that and return proper response.